# Как получить массив точек на Yandex map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Нужно объединить множество точек в кластеры. Для этого необходимо их сначала получить  и поместить в массив.

Каким образом получить точки с карты, если они добавляются через конструктор карт, а не иным способом,  к примеру, json  или тянуться от куда-то из админки?

```
ymaps.ready(init);
 var myMap;
function init () {
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
     myMap = new ymaps.Map('map',  {
            center: [55,57],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl', 'searchControl']
        });
    searchMap();
    ymaps.geolocation.get().then(function (res) {
        var mapContainer = $('#map'),
            bounds = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy');
       myMap.setCenter([bounds[0][0],bounds[0][1]]);
      searchMap();

    });

     function searchMap () {
   var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({

        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search',

            noCentering:true
        }
    });
        myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
        searchControl.search('Аптеки');
        searchControl.options.set('visible', false);

    }
    // Класетры
}
```

Comment: Закройте вопрос, корректно сформулированный уже есть отдельно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839873/Яндекс-карты-и-кластеры-js

Answer (score 1):

Карту Конструктора нельзя кастомизировать через JS API. Чтобы кластеризовать точки, размеченные в Конструкторе, Вам нужно экспортировать данные карты из интерфейса Конструктора, а затем захостить файл у себя и подключать в JS API, например, в формате JSON.

Comment: Не реально . На карту выводятся все точки аптек...Надо как то через controls.get дернуть

Comment: Так вы всё-таки про Конструктор карт или про поиск организаций?  Что кластеризоваться должно?

Comment: Да, я наверно не правильно  задал вопрос . Есть карта туда выводятся все Аптеки searchControl.search('Аптеки'); Мне необходимо  получить массив этих поинтов, но что то не получается. Весь код карты изложен ,выше.