# Как кластеризовать результаты поиска по организациям

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

на сайте есть карта ,  которая выводит все Аптеки через **searchControl.search('Аптеки')** . Их необходимо сгруппировать в кластеры.
Чтоб сгруппировать их , необходимо массив с Поинтами. Чтоб получить его использовал **searchControl.getResultsArray()**. Но как его вытащить из этой функции , чтоб продолжить с ним работу ?

```
    function searchMap () {
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({

    options: {
        provider: 'yandex#search',

        noCentering:true
    }
    });

    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
    //searchControl.search('Аптеки');
    searchControl.options.set('visible', false);

    searchControl.search('Аптеки').then(function () {
         var geoObjectsArray = searchControl.getResultsArray();
         console.log(geoObjectsArray);
    });


}
```

Или может есть какой другой способ получить  поинты с карты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`searchControl` в API предназанчен для поиска конечным пользователем карты. Переопределять результаты поиска по организациям из JS API запрещено условиями использования - сам сервис определенным образом размещает метки, раскрашивает их и т.п.

Если задача требует работать с результатами поиска как с обычными объектами (то есть реализовать не сценарий пользовательского поиска), вам подойдет [HTTP API Геопоиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch?from=SO) (Поиска по организациям). Он позволяет получить список организаций в формате JSON, а потом уже можно как угодно манипулировать ими на карте.

Comment: Тоесть мне 100% надо прибегать к HTTP API , для кластеризации точек на карте ?

Comment: Если Вы хотите кластеризовать объекты базы поиска по организациям Яндекса, то да.

Comment: :D Я выкрутился вот таким вот [образом](http://prntscr.com/jus54z)

Comment: Но столкнулся с рядом проблем , когда зум выкручиваю на 0 , то объекты не подгружаются , например если перейти в какой нибудь большой город миллионик где этих АПТЕК  очень много  он не чего не покажет

Comment: @Goryyn ну вот это и есть нарушение условий использования. Нельзя переопределять внешний вид результатов поиска из searchControl; вид этих меток - это часть рекламы и брендирования. Собственно отчасти поэтому у вас и возник "ряд проблем" - контрол заточен под другое.

Comment: А как я их переопределил ? Пришел массив по запросу Аптеки ,я его засунул в clusterer и все . В чем нарушение ?

Comment: @Goryyn вы скрываете сам searchControl, в котором отображается реклама, ломаете ранжирование (список результатов поиска), отображаете метки в кластерах, хотя цвет самих пинов и выбор, какие именно показать на карте зависит от ранжирования. В общем, это ровно то, что в ПС называется "видоизменять данные, полученные от API".

Comment: Не подскажите  как работать с API геопоиска по организациям? Или ссылку на пример , зарегался ключ получил , но как прикрутить не понимаю

Comment: Что скажешь по данному поводу ?