# API Yandex maps поиск по организациям

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-places-api

Стоит вопрос кластеризации объектов из поиска! Изначально 
 использовал **searchControl.search('Аптеки')** потом через **searchControl.getResultsArray()** получал массивы данных и кластеризовал их **clusterer.add(resultObjects);**. Но как показала практика точки собираются хаотично и вечно подгружаются (так как Аптек оччччень много) кластеризация начинает работать коряво. Еще из ответов на мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839873/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC) выяснилось  что  это нарушение условий пользования:(

1. Получил ключ **API поиск по организациям** , но как его прикрутить,
   как работать с данным которые возвращает запрос ?
2. Ради интереса ввел поисковый запрос  в строку браузера [https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Аптеки&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=API-ключ](https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=API-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87) , но  он вернул  несколько результатов... а их должно быть неизбитое кол-во!

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить данные из JSON на карту можно, например, с помощью [`geoQuery`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.xml?from=SO). В песочнице [есть пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/data_load_jquery?from=SO).

Чтобы получить все нужные результаты важно корректно формировать запрос, как описано [в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/request-docpage/?from=SO). Например, по умолчанию API возвращает максимум 10 результатов, при этом у Вас не указано, какие это должны быть результаты. Поэтому вы получаете не более 10 каких-то аптек из базы Яндекса.

Корректный запрос в Вашем случае будет, например, таким:

```
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Аптеки&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&results=500&bbox=36.83,55.67~38.24,55.91&apikey=<API-ключ>
```

Где:

- `results=500` означает, что нужно запросить максимум результатов одним запросом,
- `bbox=36.83,55.67~38.24,55.91` определяет область карты, в которой нужно искать результаты в первую очередь.

В итоге код получится каким-то таким:

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Аптеки&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&results=500&bbox=36.83,55.67~38.24,55.91&apikey=<API-ключ>', function (json) {
    var geoObjects = ym.geoQuery(json)
            .addToMap(myMap)
            .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
```

Обратите внимание, что если результатов по запросу более 500, то Вам нужно будет сделать несколько запросов на получение данных, используя параметр `skip`. При этом через API нельзя гарантировано выгрузить все-все организации, потому что это API поиска, а не каталог базы, который можно "перебрать".

Comment: Как я вычитал skip в документации это объекты которое необходимо пропустить. Или Вы что то имеете в виду другое ?

Comment: @Goryyn допустим, всего доступно 1400 объектов, вы за один запрос можете получить максимум 500. Чтобы получить все 1400 нужно сделать 3 запроса, во втором сделать skip=500 и запросить результаты 501-1000, а потом ещё запрос со skip=1000, чтобы получить результаты 1001-1400

Comment: Понял , запросы  делать  циклом или как? Чтоб костылей не наделать ? Есть примеры ? Я вижу вы документацию вдоль и поперек перечитали

Comment: Я вот о чем подумал ,  а откуда взять координаты моей геопозиции чтоб воткнуть их в параметр bbox ? Пробую через result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy');  но не едет